# Let be $Z_1, Z_2, \cdots, Z_n$ independent random variables with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2 < \infty$. Let $X_n=Z_1+Z_2+\cdots, Z_n$.

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification, stochastic-processes

Let be $Z_1, Z_2, \cdots, Z_n$ independent random variables with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2 < \infty$. Let $X_n=Z_1+Z_2+\cdots, Z_n$. I'm trying to prove that $\mathbb{E}(X_nX_m)=\min(n,m)\sigma^2$ by induction on $n$.

My attempt: First of all, note that $Var(Z_i)=\sigma^2 = \mathbb{E}(Z^{2}_{i})+\mathbb{E}^2(Z_{i}) \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}(Z_{i}^2)=\sigma^2$.

Suppose that $\mathbb{E}(X_nX_m)=\min(n,m)\sigma^2$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and fixing $m$. I want to conclude that $\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}X_m)=\min(n+1,m)\sigma^2$. By definition: $\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}X_m)=\mathbb{E}[(X_n+Z_{n+1})X_m]=\mathbb{E}[X_nX_m]+\mathbb{E}[Z_{n+1}X_m]=\min(n,m)\sigma^2+\mathbb{E}[Z_{n+1}X_m]$.

Where $Z_{n+1}X_m= Z_{n+1}(Z_1+Z_2+\cdots, Z_m)=Z_{n+1}Z_1+Z_{n+1}Z_2+\cdots+Z_{n+1}Z_m$. If we apply $\mathbb{E}$ both sides $\mathbb{E}[Z_{n+1}X_m]=\mathbb{E}(Z^{2}_{m})=\mathbb{E}(Z^{2}_{n+1})=\sigma^2$ when $m=n+1$, and for independence $\mathbb{E}(Z_{i}Z_{j})=0$ . Hence,

$\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}X_m)=\min(n,m)\sigma^2+\sigma^2 = \sigma^2\left(\min(n,m)+1\right)$. Is everything I have done correct? If so, how could I conclude to get the result?

Comment: I would't bother with using induction so formally. Just assume $m < n$ and split the sum $X_n$ at index $m$

Comment: Partially correct. You lack a base case of $n=1$. Also, I suppose in "suppose that" I believe you are trying to prove **for all $m\in \mathbb N$ and fixing $n$**. Also, in the proof after "When $Z_{n+1}X_m$ ..." I suppose you assumed that $m\ge n+1$, right? One way to check your solution is to check whether you have listed all your assumptions. For the essence to your post, I am going to add "proof-verification" into the tags.